# Asp.net Core 3.1 Serilog not working with Azure Webapp

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, serilog

So I want to use serilog with a config that looks like this, in program.cs:

```
 .UseSerilog((provider, ContextBoundObject, loggerConfig) =>
               {
                   var name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName();
                   loggerConfig

                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                    .Enrich.WithAspnetcoreHttpcontext(provider, AddCustomContextInfo)
                    .Enrich.WithProperty("Assembly", $"{name.Name}")
                    .Enrich.WithProperty("Version", $"{name.Version}")
                    .WriteTo.Debug()
                    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("LoggingConnection"),
                    "ApplicationLogs", autoCreateSqlTable: true,
                    columnOptions: MSSqlSerilogConfig.GetSqlColumnOptions(), batchPostingLimit: 1, period: new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1))

                    ;
               })
```

And this works fantastic on premise and during development. 
But now I need this to run in Azure. 
And it breaks because the connection string is null. 
So the azure portal configuration "tap"/window connectionstring is not loaded at the start for some reason. 
I found a post suggesting I should move it into startup.cs so I did. 
[ASP.Net Core 2.1 Serilog SQL Server Sink using Azure SQL is working locally but not from Azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317910/asp-net-core-2-1-serilog-sql-server-sink-using-azure-sql-is-working-locally-but)

It no longer complains about the connectionstring, However, now I can't get a valid serviceprovider for the httpcontext, that I need for the enricher 
`.Enrich.WithAspnetcoreHttpcontext(-The IServiceProvider-, AddCustomContextInfo)`.
Commenting out the line makes the project run.

The Error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at
 Serilog.Enrichers.AspnetcoreHttpcontext.LoggerEnrichmentConfigurationExtensions.WithAspnetcoreHttpcontext
(LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrichmentConfiguration, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Func`2 customMethod)
```

The AddCustomContextInfo Method Info:

```
public static UserIdentity AddCustomContextInfo(IHttpContextAccessor ctx)
{
   HttpContext context = ctx.HttpContext;
   ...
}
```

I am at a loss as to how I am supposed to get a serviceprovider that works like the one you get from program.cs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same issue as me where the connectionstring is null during program.cs.

Found out that Azure adds the connectionstrings as an environment variable see here: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/

So all I had to do was add this to my config builder in program.cs:

```
  ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables(); // this was missing
...

            config = builder.Build();
```

Now the app launches and doesn't complain about a missing connectionstring.